# Are there any forms of primes which are known to be finite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Everyone always asks about whether forms like, say, $x^2+1$, or $n!!-1$, or sums of digits of $\pi$, or any number of others, are prime infinitely many times.

Are there any forms of primes describable in roughly that sort of way which are known to be *finite*?

If anyone is seeking further clarification on what I mean by "forms of primes", [this Wikipedia category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Prime_number_classes) is exactly the sort of thing I mean.

Comment: The set of even primes are well-known to be finite. But that seems too trivial to really be interesting.

Comment: Heh. I anticipate that any answer that _can_ be given to this will be trivial to some degree, so I think I'll settle for the least trivial I see. Looks like you're off to an early lead.

Comment: What is $x$ ???

Comment: Let  $S$ be the set of prime $p$ such  that there exist $x,y,z\in \Bbb Z^+$ with  $x^p+y^p=z^p.$ After showing there do not exist $x,y,z\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $x^4+y^4=z^4,$ it is easy to show that Fermat's Last Theorem holds iff $S=\{2\}.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By clicking on some of the links on the page you linked to, one finds that [truncatable primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncatable_prime) (of three sorts) and [minimal primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_prime_(recreational_mathematics)) are finite sets.

Comment: I suspect this is the best answer I'm going to get.... I'm surprised there's not more discussion about this lack of finity, though!

Answer (score 1):

Yes any univariate integer coefficient polynomial like $3x^2+5x+2$ ( aka with even number of odd coefficients and an even constant term, Also an odd number of odd coefficients with an odd constant term, or all even coefficients and an even constant term) is alway even evaluated at integers, so only at $x=0$ could it be prime. You can turn this multivariate if you think hard.  These are all examples of the trivial even primes are finite argument, this can be done with any prime constant term though.